# Devexpress Winforms DataGridView: Deactivate "Drag Column Header here to group by that column"-Option

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

How do I deactivate the function to group by column header, which is shown in top of a datagridview-control by devExpress? 
So which option does the control have to deactivate it, something like: controlGroupOption = false?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide the group panel, set the `GridView.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel` property to `False`

To hide the group panel text, set the `GridView.GroupPanelText` property to `" "` string (a space character).

Comment: Thanks, thats it! I'll mark your answer as soon as it's allowed :)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you to go though [Disabling Grouping](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument694/DISABLING%20GROUPING) section in the XtraGrid documentation.

To prevent an end-user from changing grouping settings, you can use a number of properties.

- The [GridOptionsView.ShowGroupPanel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsView_ShowGroupPaneltopic.aspx) property specifies the visibility of a [group panel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument530.aspx). If the panel is invisible, end-users will not be able to group data using drag-and-drop. In this case, the order of the group columns can only be determined by end-users using group row captions.
- Disable the column header menu and group panel menu using the [GridOptionsMenu.EnableColumnMenu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsMenu_EnableColumnMenutopic.aspx) and [GridOptionsMenu.EnableGroupPanelMenu](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsMenu_EnableGroupPanelMenutopic.aspx) properties. Note that you can also customize these menus as described in the [Implementing Custom Behavior for Popup Menus](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/CustomDocument709.aspx) topic.
- The [GridOptionsCustomization.AllowGroup](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsCustomization_AllowGrouptopic.aspx) property specifies whether or not end-users can apply data grouping in a View. If this property's value is false, grouping is available only in code. If this property is set to true, end-users can group data if grouping and sorting is enabled for the desired column.
- The [GridOptionsCustomization.AllowSort](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsCustomization_AllowSorttopic.aspx) property specifies whether or not end-users can apply data sorting. Data cannot be grouped if sorting is disabled.
- A column's OptionsColumn.AllowGroup option controls whether or not end-users can apply grouping to that column.
- A column's [OptionsColumn.AllowSort](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowSorttopic.aspx) option determines whether or not end-users can sort rows against a column. As stated above, grouping is only available if a column supports sorting.
- A column's [OptionsColumn.AllowMove](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowMovetopic.aspx) and View's [GridOptionsCustomization.AllowColumnMoving](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridOptionsCustomization_AllowColumnMovingtopic.aspx) options control whether or not end-users can move the column. Since grouping implies moving a column onto a group panel, you can disable grouping just by preventing a column from being moved.

Code snippet to disable grouping for the a column in a view.

```
gridView1.Columns["fieldName"].OptionsColumn.AllowGroup = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
```

//

```
DevExpress.XtraGrid.GridControl gridControl;
DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView gridView;

to enable grouping capability
gridView.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = true

to disable
gridView.OptionsView.ShowGroupPanel = false
```

Comment: Thank you for that big answer, but all I needed was the small control on the top ;) The other ones are left on, but the top had to be deleted for space reasons

Comment: If you have solved your issue then it is good. If not then attach a screen shot that what exactly you want to do...:)

Comment: I achieved what I wanted to :) Thanks!